# Intergation of Differential Forms

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, tensors, exterior-algebra

MTW Gravitation Chap. 4. ELECTROMAGNETISM AND DIFFERENTIAL FORMS Pg 100

In differential forms, the $\bf{Faraday}$ has the definition:
$$ \mathbf{F}= \frac{1}{2} F_{\alpha \beta} \mathbf{d}x^{\alpha} \wedge \mathbf{d}x^{\beta} \tag{1}$$ 
For an infinitesimal surface $\bf{u \wedge v}$ and for general $\bf{F}$
$$\int_{surface} \mathbf{F}=\int_{\mathbf{u} \wedge \mathbf{v}} \mathbf{F}=\mathbf{F(\bf{u,v})} \tag{2}$$
But I do not see how the second equality in (2) holds.

---

My attempt to derive the result:

Parameterise the surface by generic points 
$$\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{P}(\lambda^1, \lambda^2) \tag{3}$$

Using the computational rule for integration:

$$\int_{surface} \mathbf{F}= \int <\mathbf{F}, \frac{\partial \mathcal{P}}{\partial \lambda^1} \wedge \frac{\partial \mathcal{P}}{\partial \lambda^2}>d\lambda^1 d\lambda^2 \tag{4}$$

Since $$ \frac{\partial \mathcal{P}}{\partial \lambda^1} \wedge \frac{\partial \mathcal{P}}{\partial \lambda^2}= \mathbf{u \wedge v} \tag{5}$$

(4) becomes $$\int <\mathbf{F}, \mathbf{u} \wedge \mathbf{v}>d\lambda^1 d\lambda^2 \tag{6}$$

Expressing (6) in terms of its components, I got
$$\int <\frac{1}{2} F_{\alpha \beta} \mathbf{d}x^{\alpha} \wedge \mathbf{d}x^{\beta}, u^{\rho}\mathbf{e_{\rho}} \wedge v^{\sigma}\mathbf{e_{\sigma}}>d\lambda^1 d\lambda^2 \tag{7}$$

Or equivalently $$\int \frac{1}{2} F_{\alpha \beta} u^{\rho}v^{\sigma}<\mathbf{d}x^{\alpha} \wedge \mathbf{d}x^{\beta}, \mathbf{e_{\rho}} \wedge \mathbf{e_{\sigma}}>d\lambda^1 d\lambda^2 \tag{8}$$
which simplifies to
$$\int \frac{1}{2} F_{\alpha \beta} u^{\rho}v^{\sigma} \delta^{\alpha \beta}_{\rho \sigma}d\lambda^1 d\lambda^2= \int \frac{1}{2} F_{\alpha \beta} u^{\alpha}v^{\beta} d\lambda^1 d\lambda^2\tag{9}$$
and is the closest expression to $$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u,v})=F_{\alpha \beta}u^{\alpha}v^{\beta} \tag{10}$$
that I can get.

How can I proceed from (9) to obtain (2), or rather how can I remove the integral and the 1/2 factor in (9)? Or is there any misconception in my working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points: First, we are assuming $F_{\alpha\beta} = -F_{\beta\alpha}$; the factor of $1/2$ is there because we are summing over all $\alpha,\beta$ rather than over $\alpha<\beta$. At the end, you are missing terms: You should in fact have $u^\alpha v^\beta - u^\beta v^\alpha$, and this, together with skew symmetry of $F$, will get rid of the $1/2$.

Second, when you parametrize the parallelogram, you have $0\le \lambda^1,\lambda^2 \le 1$, so the double integral of the constant over the unit square gives you what you want. (Remember that they are being intuitive here, and on an "infinitesimal surface" they treat the coefficients $F_{\alpha\beta}$ as constants.)

Comment: So am I missing the $u^{\alpha}v^{\beta}-u^{\beta}v^{\alpha}$ term in the integral of $(9)$ or in the eq. $(10)$?

Comment: In (9). Simplifying this and then integrating (as I suggested) will give (10).

Comment: But not in (8)? So is it the Kronecker Delta conversion from $(8) to (9)$ that went wrong then? Excuse my ignorance but I am very new to exterior algebra.

Comment: You have an ironic name ... Chern (who happens to have been my adviser!) was the world master of differential forms :P (I assume you're a physicist who wants to play with Chern-Simons invariants.) Remember that you will get two nonzero terms from $\delta^{\alpha\beta}_{\rho\sigma}$: $+1$ when $\rho=\alpha, \sigma=\beta$ and $-1$ when $\rho=\beta, \sigma=\alpha$. :)

Comment: He's just someone I admire very much of. You were very fortunate to have him as your adviser then! Actually I'm just a high school student who's very interested in differential geometry, and yes the CS theory is my ultimate goal (hopefully will get there in the next four or five years!). Anyway it all makes sense now, thanks for explaining Ted :)

Comment: By the way, if you know multivariable calculus and want to learn some classical differential geometry, check out my free text (linked in my profile).